# What datastructure can be used alternate to 4 dimensional array

Tags: c, arrays

Currently in my testframework, to keep track of testresults , I am maintaining 4D array : TestResult[domain][client][testno][resourceno]

The testcase basically has 3 loops

```
    For each domain(0-2)  
    For each client(0-8)   
    For each resource(0-8)
    Execute test1
    Store TestResult
    Execute test2
    Store TestResult
```

Is there a better datastructure which can be used in C, for this purpose other than 4D array?

Comment: Would you please define "better"?

Comment: you could also use a struct  to store the results. structs and arrays are basically the only data structures in C.

Comment: If each test is performed for each domain, client and resource, and it is not possible that for some domain some client is skipped for example, and from your pseudocode it looks like this is the case, then 4D array is actually a very good idea, I don't see a reason to change it. It will give you the easiest and the fastest way to make search or filter on test results.

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's get to the opposite extrem:

```
typedef struct
{
    // whatever you need...
} Resource;

typedef struct
{
    Resource a;
    Resource b;
    // ...
    Resource g;
} Client;

typedef struct
{
    Client a;
    Client b;
    // ...
    Client g;
} Domain;
```

OK, I skipped the `Test` struct and the one containing the all the domains, the idea should still be clear...

```
void processResource(Resource* resource)
{ /* ... */ }

void processClient(Client* c)
{
    processResource(&c->a);
    // ...
    processResource(&c->g);
}

void processDomain(Domain* d)
{
    processClient(&d->a);
    // ...
    processClient(&d->g);
}
```

As already mentioned: it is the other extreme. You might maintain arrays within your structs, such that you might iterate over as:

```
void processDomain(Domain* d)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(d->clients)/sizeof(*d->clients); ++i)
    {
        processResource(d->clients + i);
    }
}
```

Or have some lower n-dimensional arrays within some of the structs. Any combination would do the trick, all up to you, whatever you consider most appropriate...

You could even extend to dynamic arrays:

```
typedef struct
{
    Resource* resources;
    size_t count;
} Client;
```

if you consider managing variable numbers of sub-elements useful.

If all this is *'better'* than the original 4D-array? Mainly a matter of taste, I'd say, unless perhaps a better chance of reusability especially of the lower nested structs, but current use-case appears too specific for this really applying here.